# Effect after <a href="#">

Tags: html, css, highlight

I have a `<div>` with a section id like this:

```
<style>
.div1 {
padding: 10px;
background: #888;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
border-radius: 10px;
color: white;
margin-right: 10px;
}
</style>

<section id="test">
<div class="div1">
...
</div></section>
```

On another page I have a link to this page:

```
<a href="index.php/page2#test">Click here</a>
```

It works fine, but what I would like to do is: when I click the link, it should go to the `section id` and highlight the div or something similar (just an highlight like a blink, so the users know, which "box" it is).
Maybe, I should say, I have 3 divs like this side by side, but only the last one has the `<section id="test">` so I would like this one to be highlighted.

Thanks

Comment: You could use the [target-trick](https://bitsofco.de/the-target-trick/)... Really experimental but it works.

Comment: @Maharkus — this is regular, normal, completely non-experimental use of the entire standard and well-supported `:target` pseudo-class.

Comment: @quentin Thank you, but I was thinking a little more like a "blink" or something. I know I wrote light up, but ment like when you hover a button and then remove the mouse again :) Sorry, not that good at english :) You understand?

Comment: @Daniel It doesn't matter what you want to do with it; you do that the same way you normally light up an element, with an animation or a transition.

Comment: @MrLister Okay, I'll try :) Thanks

Comment: When I click my link, it moves to the section, but it doesn't light up, but if I refresh the page it suddently light up?